# How to change value of closest input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick

I have a table with multiple rows, all structured the same. I created a DIV that can be clicked. If an user clicks the DIV, the value of the input in the same row should change. With the code below, all inputfields changes with the same value. How can I adjust the code to make javascript changes only the corresponding input?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="inp-hid">
</td>
<td>
<div class="acts-like-btn"></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="inp-hid">
</td>
<td>
<div class="acts-like-btn"></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input class="inp-hid">
</td>
<td>
<div class="acts-like-btn"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>



<script>
$(this).parents().find('.inp-hid').val("yes");
</script>
```

Comment: *"I created a DIV that can be clicked"* - It would be better to use an `<a>` element (either in the `<div>` or instead of it), because then the element would "click"-able via the keyboard (for users who don't have a mouse or other pointing device).

Answer (score 2):

Add a click event on your button that grabs the row it is into `closest('tr')` then in the row finds the input `find('input')` to set the val.

```
$('.acts-like-btn').on('click', function () {
  $(this)
    .closest('tr')
    .find('input').val('yes');
});
```

In your code

```
$(this).parents().find('.inp-hid').val("yes");
```

This is grabbing the `window` object and from there finding all `.inp-hid` elements, instead of the row.

See

- [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)
- [jQuery.closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [jQuery.find](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [jQuery.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)